# How to get the value within the below expression in java

Tags: java, split

I want to get the value within the **[" "]** of the below expression in Java.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">["*Friends"]</string>
```

Could you please help me, How to get the ***Friends** as result from the above string.

Comment: Use a parser or write your own.

Comment: either use xml parser or regular expression to get it.

Comment: `String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`, `String#indexOf(String str)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very hacky solution and not tested:

```
String xml = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">[\"*Friends\"]</string>";
String tag = xml.substring(xml.indexOf(">[\"")+3,xml.indexOf("\"]>"));
```